# How can I create an expandable grid of Swing buttons?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to make an A* Pathfinding Visualizer but right now I am stuck on creating the grid. What is the best way of creating a grid like what is seen below? For instance, should I just use a bunch of `JButton` components or is there some other way?

[image: What I am trying to do]

Comment: Do they need to do something when clicked? Yes: use `JButton`. No: Use `JLabel`. Put them (either) in a `GridLayout`. BTW = what do you mean by 'expandable'? Does the number of rows / columns need to change after the grid is created, or does 'expand' refer to the user making the GUI bigger?

Comment: I am afraid there are many good answers for this questions and it depends entirely on what is best in your case. You can of course use "JButtons", or JPanels (with painted border) or you can simply draw a Canvas. The Canvas would be wait easier for graphical solutions, the JPanels may be quicker to implement, and the JButtons might be easier for user interaction.... but again many possible answers.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yeah I'll need to change the color and mark the clicked button's position in some type of data structure.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yeah the user will be able to edit how big the grid is.

Comment: *"how big the grid is"* That does not narrow it down between the two, since it can be interpreted to mean either. So, specifically: Do you mean changing the **number of columns / rows?** Note also that you are the only person with actual interest in solving this, for everyone else, it's purely academic. So now is a good time for you to put more words, rather than less, as my interest in helping is fading with every answer I need to clarify.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I mean a changing number of columns and rows that users can define.

Comment: Write your own Swing component class (Just extend JPanel - it's the simple). Give it a border, a fixed width and height (or at least make it respect the aspect ratio) and then add a click listener so it can react on user interaction. You can hold the instances in a list and they can all keep track of their own coordinates in the grid, the class should also be able to tell you if it is part of the path (like `isPathElement()` or `getPathIndex()` for an advanced implementation). Why don't you try your implementation first, then edit your question when you have more questions.

Comment: @GameDroids *"Just extend JPanel - it's the simple"* Not as simple as using a `JButton` with an `ActionListener`. OP: OK .. I was thinking to recommend using a `CardLayout` to switch between an R x C grid and an R+N x C+M grid, but a) that would need some handling to pack the top level container, and b) once a larger grid had been added, the GUI would not later pack down to fit a smaller grid. So `JButton` in a `GridLayout`, using `removeAll()` on the panel before setting a new grid layout to change the number of columns and/or rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Put `JButton` components in a `GridLayout`, using `removeAll()` on the panel before setting a new grid layout to change the number of columns and/or rows. Lastly `pack()` the top level container (in this case a `JFrame`) to fit the number of rows and columns.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class ChangableButtonGrid {

    private JComponent ui = null;
    JPanel gridArea = new JPanel();

    public static final int SIZE = 600;
    JToolBar tools = new JToolBar("Tools");
    SpinnerNumberModel colModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(20, 5, 50, 1);
    SpinnerNumberModel rowModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(5, 5, 50, 1);
    ChangeListener changeListener = (ChangeEvent e) -> {
        refresh();
    };

    public ChangableButtonGrid() {
        initUI();
    }

    public final void initUI() {
        if (ui!=null) return;

        ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4,4));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4,4,4,4));

        ui.add(gridArea);

        ui.add(tools,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        tools.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
        addModelToToolbar("Cols", colModel);
        addModelToToolbar("Rows", rowModel);

        ui.add(gridArea);
    }

    private void refresh() {
        int cols = colModel.getNumber().intValue();
        int rows = rowModel.getNumber().intValue();
        gridArea.removeAll();
        gridArea.setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, cols));
        for (int rr=0; rr<rows; rr++) {
            for (int cc=0; cc<cols; cc++) {
                JButton b = new JButton(cc + "," + rr);
                gridArea.add(b);
            }
        }
        Container c = gridArea.getTopLevelAncestor();
        JFrame f = (JFrame)c;
        f.pack();
    }

    private void addModelToToolbar(String label, SpinnerNumberModel model) {
        tools.add(new JLabel(label));
        JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(model);
        spinner.addChangeListener(changeListener);
        tools.add(spinner);
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = () -> {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            ChangableButtonGrid o = new ChangableButtonGrid();

            JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

            f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
            f.pack();
            o.refresh();

            f.setVisible(true);
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```